# Perl base64 returns different

Tags: perl, base64

When I run Perl base64 it returns string which is different from the ones ([online encoding system](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/)) returned. What could be the cause of this?

This is how I get base64 of my image.

```
use MIME::Base64;

open (IMAGE, "C:\\wamp\\www\\image.png") or die "$!";
$raw_string = do{ local $/ = undef; <IMAGE>; };
$encoded = encode_base64( $raw_string );
```

Answer (score 7):

You're missing

```
binmode(IMAGE);
```